# Función salto de fila CSV

Tags: python, csv, flask

Disculpen si mi titulo no es muy claro, es la primera vez que hago una pregunta en este sitio, una disculpa de antemano y espero que mi explicacion sea lo mas clara posible.
Estoy intentando hacer un formulario con Flask y Python, quiero guardar los elementos que obtengo de los templates en un archivo CSV.

Hice una función que deberia guardar los datos de los templates en una fila y cuando llegue al ultimo template guardar en la fila del CSV y hacer un salto de fila.

Intente realizar una funcion pero en lugar de guardar la información en la misma fila del csv, lo que hace es escribir el ultimo elemento obtenido del template en una fila nueva, y deberia guardarse en la misma fila:
[image: Ejemplo de información guardada en el CSV]

El código de la función es el siguiente:

```
def write(test,final):
lista=[]
for x in test:
    print(test[x])
    lista.append(test[x])
with open('covid.csv', 'a') as f:
    if final == '0':
        print("Dentro de if 0")
        for line in lista:
            name=io.StringIO(line)
            coma=io.StringIO(",")
            f.write(str(name.read()))
            f.write(str(coma.read()))
    if final == '1':
        print("Dentro de if 1")
        for line in lista:
            name=io.StringIO(line)
            coma=io.StringIO(",")
            f.write(str(name.read()))
            f.write(str(coma.read()))
        f.write(str("\n"))
```

Esta función la mando llamar de la siguiente manera:

```
@app.route('/sintomas', methods=['GET','POST'])
def sintomas():
    print("Prueba de datos:")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        test = request.form.to_dict()
        print(test)
        write(test,'0')
    return render_template('nuevaplantilla6.html')

@app.route('/signos', methods=['GET','POST'])
def sintomas2():
    print("Prueba de datos:")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        test = request.form.to_dict()
        print(test)
        write(test,'1')
    return render_template('plantilla7.html')
```